# Is it possible to lmake local modifications to built-in extensions of vscode?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I've been using markdown cells with a lot of math expressions in Jupyter notebooks. I noticed that in when I define a macro inside one math expression, the macro won't get carried over to the next expression.

There is a [pull request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/148006) from vscode github repository that fixes the issue by modifying the code for markdown-math (a built-in extension of VSC). The problem is that the PR has not been approved. Is it possible for me to make similar modifications to my local VSC, or do I have to wait for the PR to be approved and VSC to be updated by MS?

Thanks.

Comment: you can compile the `Markdown-Math` extension containing the PR, disable the internal copy and install your own build

Comment: Yeah you can change them. The place to start is figuring out where they live on your system so you can read there package manifest, and that sort a thing. On linux they are @ /usr/share/code/resources/app/extensions. If your using mac or windows you'll have to find out what the equivalent path is for the linux path I gave you. Mac will probably be similar.

Comment: It should be noted though, that its easier to just write your own extension. Unless you know of some hack to do that involves F'ing  around with the built-in extensions, I don't see any reason why a person would do it. You can also disable them, flat out delete them. VS Code is open source, and for MS to label it as such, they have to allow you to do what you want with the program.

Comment: Its also important to note, any updates or upgrades will very likely overwrite anything you add to the built-in extension's files &/or directories. It could even possibly prevent you from upgrading all together. If that were the case, it would require you to save your custom built-in extension, delete vscode, DL & install the newest version, then add your custom extensions again. Becuase VS Code drops a major release each month, you would have to do that each month, assuming vscode won't upgrade because of your changes.

Comment: The best reason for tearing apart, and adding to the built-ins would simply be to learn how they work. You would probably learn somthing you didn't know be fore you started. :-)